# SMB mount with Kerberos

Tags: fedora, active-directory, kerberos, smb, smbclient

I have set up a server with Fedora 33 and joined it to an Active Directory. This worked successful and users can authenticate themselves with their Active Directory user names. I can also see my Linux computer in the Active Directory under "Computers".

Now I would like to mount a SMB share. However, I am unable to do so and I don't know why.

I log in to the server using my AD username and password, which works fine. I can also list my Kerberos tickets:

```
$ klist
Ticket cache: KCM:1089742435:31950
Default principal: username@DOMAIN

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
02/10/2021 11:14:34  02/10/2021 21:14:34  krbtgt/DOMAIN@DOMAIN
    renew until 02/11/2021 11:14:34
```

so far, this looks good in my opinion. Then, I try to list the SMB shares:

```
smbclient -L //server/share -m SMB3 -k
```

however, this fails, even though I should have access with my Kerberos ticket. The error shown is:

```
gensec_spnego_client_negTokenInit_step: gse_krb5: creating NEG_TOKEN_INIT for cifs/nas-iap.unibe.ch failed (next[(null)]): NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
```

I don't understand this error. If I try without the `-k` parameter, the username is correct and I can enter my AD password and see all shares:

```
$ smbclient -L //server/share -m SMB3
Enter username@DOMAIN's password: 

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    (fancy list of all shares available)
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

What is interesting, though, is that `kinit -k` fails for reasons I don't understand:

```
$ kinit -k
kinit: Client 'host/computername@DOMAIN' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials
```

My first step should be to be able to mount the SMB shares. Later on I would like to add them to the `fstab` with the `multiuser` option.

Comment: `kinit-k` means something different (get a ticket from a keytab) so that’s a red herring

Comment: Have you solved it? I see similar stuff on SLES with my try to use kerberos with `smbclient`.